# Python - find text in a string, then grab text X spaces ahead?

Tags: python-2.7

Given this -

```
string = "this is text. here is what I want. stop."
```

I want to search the string for the word `text`, then move forward until I find the word `stop`.  If this seems odd, I am making selenium webdriver tests to grab text from the page source (source without proper ids/names/etc.  Kinda a pain).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet:

```
import re
string = "this is text. here is what I want. stop."
match = re.match("^.*text(.*)stop.*$", string)
print(match.groups()[0])
```

Output:

```
. here is what I want.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```
>>> string = "this is text. here is what I want. stop."
>>> x = re.split('(\W)', string)
>>> x
['this', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'text', '.', '', ' ', 'here', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'what', ' ', 'I', ' ', 'want', '.', '', ' ', 'stop', '.', '']
>>> for k in range(0, len(x)):
...     if x[k] == 'text':
...             cur = 'text'
...             arr = []
...             while cur != 'stop':
...                     cur = x[k+1]
...                     k+=1
...                     arr.append(cur)
...             break
... 
>>> arr
['.', '', ' ', 'here', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'what', ' ', 'I', ' ', 'want', '.', '', ' ', 'stop']
>>> ''.join(arr)
'. here is what I want.'
>>>
```

When the `for` loop reaches `'text'`, then it keeps going until it hits stop, at which point it stops.